# How to write re-usable model and views in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js, code-reuse, reusability

I am new to backbone. I have read that it is a mv* framework where it tends to be more similar to MVP architecture that MVC architecture.

My question is if I try to implement my website by using backbone as a MVC framework, then how should I implement re-usable components?. 
For example suppose one of website's page has three subviews

1. "SubView1"
2. "SubView2"
3. "SubView3"

Each of them have there models

1. "Model1"
2. "Model2"
3. "Model3"

If Backbone is implemented in form of MVC then controller will sit between model and view and most of the logic will be written in controller, in this case if we want to use a subview and its model on some other page then the code written in controller has to be replicated, what is the alternative to it?

Comment: I would recommend checking out a view framework for backbone called `Marionette` and their `behaviors` for supporting maintainable components

Comment: You have to look to Marionettejs

Comment: *"the code written in controller has to be replicated"* - what controller? There is no controller in Backbone.js

Answer (score 2):

This is a very opinionated response...

I think `Backbone.View` is a misnomer, and should actually be considered the controller. It's generally where most of the app logic lives.

The html markup should be considered the view (should be logic-less), and of course the model is still the model.

It's hard to answer your question about re-usability without some kind of starting point. If you can provide some code, I would be happy to review it for you.